# How to create an interactive (Drag and drop stuff) GUI in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

Need to make a custom application in which i can drag and drop (predefined) items on to a workspace and move them freely, example is of in Microsoft Office PowerPoint where a workflow diagram can be made easily ...

need a start, where can i get one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this CodeProject article, concerning how to create a diagram designer in WPF:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a fun, but big project.

I'd start [here: Creating Your Own Drawing Application with Visual Basic .NET, Part 1](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/graphics/article.php/c13205). It's VB.NET, but it's a good start, and it';s all about the framework.  Hopefully, you can translate VB.NET to C#.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to learn how to make a simple drag and drop first. Try [this tutorial](http://vicky4147.wordpress.com/2007/02/04/a-simple-drag-drop-in-winforms/) or [this tutorial](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2007/07/07/basic-drag-and-drop-in-winforms.aspx). Hope this helps!